# unwanted shadow changes in eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

In the pictures you can see on the blue logo shadow change.
What can i do so my shadows are consistent throughout multiple frames ?
[image][image]

Comment: In Eeevee shadows are calculated in the viewport, meaning any object not in the frame will not have any impact on the render's shadows. What you can do is render a larger frame to make sure any occluding object has an effect on the desired frame and then crop it in post-processing

Comment: And there is no way to make it calculate all geometry ?

Comment: Not that I know of, if you're using Eevee. Alternatively you can bake the shadows with Cycles and use the textures in Eevee afterwards